# Show only the latest category of product in Laravel 5.8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.8

I have three models: products, category, product_category. A product may have many categories, and some categories may have a parent. You can find related relations below. I could show all categories with a `foreach()` loop, but I don't want to do that. I wish only to show the category, and it must be the latest. Is there a way to show only the last category of a parent category of the current product?

```php
<div class="row">
    @foreach ($products as $product)
        @foreach ($product->categories as $cat)
            {{ $cat->title }}
        @endforeach
    @endforeach
</div>
```

**Product model**

```php
public function categories()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class);
}
```

**Category model**

```php
public function products()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class);
}

public function subcategories()
{
    return $this->hasMany('\App\Category', 'parent_id');
}

public function parent()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('\App\Category', 'parent_id');
}
```

**Categories schema**

```php
$table->increments('id');
$table->string('title');
$table->integer('parent_id')->nullable();
```

**Category_product schema**

```php
$table->increments('id');
$table->integer('category_id')->unsigned();
$table->integer('product_id')->unsigned();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use query builder on the relationship like so:

`$product->categories->orderBy('id', 'desc')->first();`

That will order from most recent to oldest and you can just take the first record.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use

```
$product->categories()->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->first();
```

Or you can also try

```
 public function categories()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class)->orderBy('id','DESC');
    }
```

Then you can use

```
$product->categories()->first();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `latest()` method

```
$product->categories->latest()->first();
```

Or,

`$product->categories->orderBy('id', 'desc')->first();`

Answer (score 0):

#### Using specific methods on your model

Your categories definition would be something like this, right?

```
public function categories() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class);
}
```

So, just create another method to retrieve only the latest.

```
public function latestCategory() {
    return $this->categories()->latest();
}
```

If you need the oldest category, the same approach is applied.

```
public function oldestCategory() {
    return $this->categories()->oldest();
}
```

#### Using only the categories relationship definition

You could also apply a different approach if you do not intend to create new methods:

```
$this->categories()->latest();
```

or

```
$this->categories()->oldest();
```

Hope it will help you.
Have a great day.